# Enlarge svg group element on mouseenter (D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm attempting to enlarge an svg group element on the `mousesenter` event with the following code. Instead this code enlarges the image within this group (causing a 'zoom' like effect). When I change `images.on('mouseenter'...` to `nodeEneter.on('mouseenter...` nothing happens. My full example can be found here: http://blockbuilder.org/MattDionis/7f5375d927698f508a01

```
var node = vis.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      })
      .attr('filter', 'url(#drop-shadow)')
      .on('click', click)
      .call(force.drag);

    var images = nodeEnter.append('svg:image')
      .attr('xlink:href',  function(d) {
        return d.img;
      })
      .attr('x', function(d) {
        return -25;
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return -25;
      })
      .attr('height', 50)
      .attr('width', 50)
      .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip-circle)');

    var setEvents = images
      .on('mouseenter', function() {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .attr('x', function(d) {
            return -60;
          })
          .attr('y', function(d) {
            return -60;
          })
          .attr('height', 100)
          .attr('width', 100);
        })
```

Comment: SVG group elements don't have x, y, width or height attributes. You'd need to set a scale transform on it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Within the snippet the values for `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` are set on the `image`s not on the `g`s which should be perfectly fine.

Comment: Your example on Block builder doesn't include any event handlers for mouseenter events. This doesn't correspond to the code given in the snippet... Furthermore, when saying, you want to enlarge the group, what do you expect to happen to the images contained within if not the zoom itself?

Comment: @altocumulus the question says that when the OP changes the code so that they are on the g, nothing happens.

Comment: @altocumulus, ahhh my fault, I updated that block since posting this. I expect the 'zoom-like' behavior, but I'm aiming for the radius of that svg group to grow. Currently the radius stays the same, but the image inside is zoomed in on.

Comment: @RobertLongson You are right, I missed that.

Comment: I still don't get what you are after... A group is a simple container for the elements within. It doesn't have a radius by itself. It does have dimensions, though, which are determined by the elements it contains and you may apply transformations to it, but like @RobertLongson mentioned, there are no x, y, width and height attributes for group elements. In your example there is exactly one image per group, and setting the attributes on the images or scaling the group will zoom the images. Please try to be more precise on the effect you want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some confusion on the question but as you said ***I expect the 'zoom-like' behavior*** *here is how to achieve it...*

To increase the size of the node on mouse over just add the scale to the node.
Set the scale to 2 on mouseOver and on mouseOut set the scale back to 1.

```
 var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      })
      .attr('filter', 'url(#drop-shadow)')
      .on('mouseover', function(d){d.scale = 2;tick();})
      .on('mouseout', function(d){d.scale = 1;tick();})
      .on('click', click)
      .call(force.drag);
```

Then in side the function `nodeTransform` handle the scale

```
  function nodeTransform(d) {
    if (!d.scale)
      d.scale=1;
    d.x =  Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(width - (d.imgwidth / 2 || 16), d.x));
    d.y =  Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(height - (d.imgheight / 2 || 16), d.y));
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")scale(" +d.scale+ ")";
  }
```

Working code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/cyrilcherian/7bc4d2576a92f018b7fe/ae69aad06b744b7e9e0d640c632280e38c43de41)

Hope this helps!